# Como o servidor sabe que o index é a página principal?

Tags: html, apache

Por exemplo, tenho vários arquivos .HTML e .PHP na pasta public_html no meu servidor (Interno), mas, ao abrir o caminho no navegador (abrir o caminho http://localhost/LucasCarvalho/public_html), ele sempre abre o index.html, ao invés de abrir as pastinhas (pastinhas, digo, listar todos os arquivos/pastas que temos dentro da public_html) pra gente escolher qual página a gente quer abrir.

Por que isso? É padrão?

Comment: Qual servidor você utiliza? Tomcat, Apache, IIS...?

Comment: O servidor é o Apache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em geral é padrão do Apache, mas você pode alterar isso no arquivo `.htaccess`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

sim, é padrão. Dependendo do seu servidor Web, você pode definir qual é o documento padrão nas configurações, ou em asp.net por exemplo, define isso pelo arquivo web.config também